# when I use ons.creatDialog() to let a dialog show,there is an error

Tags: onsen-ui

My code as follows:

```
module.controller('portfoliosController', function($scope){
$scope.dialogs = {};

$scope.show = function() {
    ons.createDialog('managePort.html',{parentScope: $scope}).then(function(dialog) {
        dialog.show();
    });
};
});
```

and HTML:

```
 <div class="right" ng-click="show()" style="font-size:22px;color:white;padding-right:10px;margin-top:12px;" ><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></div>
    <script type="text/ons-template" id="managePort.html">
    <ons-dialog var="dlg" cancelable>
        <ons-list>
          <ons-list-item modifier="tappable">
            Foo
          </ons-list-item>
          <ons-list-item modifier="tappable">
            Bar
          </ons-list-item>
          <ons-list-item modifier="tappable">
            Hoge
          </ons-list-item>
        </ons-list>    
    </ons-dialog> 
</script>
```

the erorr is Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'attrs.length')

Anybody knows the reason？

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you haven't included the controller, you need to include it by using `ng-controller="portfoliosController"`

I modified a little bit your app, here is a working version:

http://codepen.io/andipavllo/pen/BodgKe

Comment: take a look at the codepen example, I made some small changes, like substituting the script tag with `<ons-template>`